# Compute and explode a range of dates between two columns in polars

Tags: date, datetime, date-range, python-polars

I need to compute all month ends between two date columns and explode the resulting lists.

```py
import polars as pl
from datetime import datetime

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "id": ["A", "A", "A", "B", "B"],
        "value": ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"],
        "valid_from": [
            datetime(2020, 1, 1),
            datetime(2021, 1, 1),
            datetime(2022, 1, 1),
            datetime(2020, 1, 1),
            datetime(2021, 1, 1),
        ],
        "valid_to": [
            datetime(2020, 12, 31),
            datetime(2021, 12, 31),
            datetime(2022, 12, 31),
            datetime(2020, 12, 31),
            datetime(2021, 12, 31),
        ],
    }
)

def __month_range(dict):
    start,end = dict.values()
    return pl.date_range(start, end, "1mo_saturating", eager=True).dt.month_end()

df.with_columns(
    pl.struct(["valid_from","valid_to"]).apply(__month_range).alias("test")
).explode("test")
```

is this the way to do it? Or is there a simpler / faster approach without using struct ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**[Update]:** [`pl.date_ranges()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.date_ranges.html#polars-date-ranges) (plural) was added in `0.18.9` which does this directly.

```py
>>> pl.date_ranges("valid_from", "valid_to")
<polars.expr.expr.Expr at 0x135015b70>
```

```py
df.with_columns(date = pl.date_ranges("valid_from", "valid_to"))
```

```
# shape: (5, 5)
# ┌─────┬───────┬─────────────────────┬─────────────────────┬───────────────────────────────────┐
# │ id  ┆ value ┆ valid_from          ┆ valid_to            ┆ date                              │
# │ --- ┆ ---   ┆ ---                 ┆ ---                 ┆ ---                               │
# │ str ┆ str   ┆ datetime[μs]        ┆ datetime[μs]        ┆ list[datetime[μs]]                │
# ╞═════╪═══════╪═════════════════════╪═════════════════════╪═══════════════════════════════════╡
# │ A   ┆ 1     ┆ 2020-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 2020-12-31 00:00:00 ┆ [2020-01-01 00:00:00, 2020-01-02… │
# │ A   ┆ 2     ┆ 2021-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 2021-12-31 00:00:00 ┆ [2021-01-01 00:00:00, 2021-01-02… │
# │ A   ┆ 3     ┆ 2022-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 2022-12-31 00:00:00 ┆ [2022-01-01 00:00:00, 2022-01-02… │
# │ B   ┆ 4     ┆ 2020-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 2020-12-31 00:00:00 ┆ [2020-01-01 00:00:00, 2020-01-02… │
# │ B   ┆ 5     ┆ 2021-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 2021-12-31 00:00:00 ┆ [2021-01-01 00:00:00, 2021-01-02… │
# └─────┴───────┴─────────────────────┴─────────────────────┴───────────────────────────────────┘
```

```py
(df.with_columns(date = pl.date_ranges("valid_from", "valid_to"))
   .explode("date")
   .with_columns(month_end = pl.col("date").dt.month_end())
)
```

```
# shape: (1_827, 6)
# ┌─────┬───────┬─────────────────────┬─────────────────────┬─────────────────────┬─────────────────────┐
# │ id  ┆ value ┆ valid_from          ┆ valid_to            ┆ date                ┆ month_end           │
# │ --- ┆ ---   ┆ ---                 ┆ ---                 ┆ ---                 ┆ ---                 │
# │ str ┆ str   ┆ datetime[μs]        ┆ datetime[μs]        ┆ datetime[μs]        ┆ datetime[μs]        │
# ╞═════╪═══════╪═════════════════════╪═════════════════════╪═════════════════════╪═════════════════════╡
# │ A   ┆ 1     ┆ 2020-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 2020-12-31 00:00:00 ┆ 2020-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 2020-01-31 00:00:00 │
# │ A   ┆ 1     ┆ 2020-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 2020-12-31 00:00:00 ┆ 2020-01-02 00:00:00 ┆ 2020-01-31 00:00:00 │
# │ A   ┆ 1     ┆ 2020-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 2020-12-31 00:00:00 ┆ 2020-01-03 00:00:00 ┆ 2020-01-31 00:00:00 │
# │ A   ┆ 1     ┆ 2020-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 2020-12-31 00:00:00 ┆ 2020-01-04 00:00:00 ┆ 2020-01-31 00:00:00 │
# │ …   ┆ …     ┆ …                   ┆ …                   ┆ …                   ┆ …                   │
# │ B   ┆ 5     ┆ 2021-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 2021-12-31 00:00:00 ┆ 2021-12-28 00:00:00 ┆ 2021-12-31 00:00:00 │
# │ B   ┆ 5     ┆ 2021-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 2021-12-31 00:00:00 ┆ 2021-12-29 00:00:00 ┆ 2021-12-31 00:00:00 │
# │ B   ┆ 5     ┆ 2021-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 2021-12-31 00:00:00 ┆ 2021-12-30 00:00:00 ┆ 2021-12-31 00:00:00 │
# │ B   ┆ 5     ┆ 2021-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 2021-12-31 00:00:00 ┆ 2021-12-31 00:00:00 ┆ 2021-12-31 00:00:00 │
# └─────┴───────┴─────────────────────┴─────────────────────┴─────────────────────┴─────────────────────┘
```

Comment: this way more elegant! thank you very much!

Comment: `ComputeError: 'start'  must contain exactly one value, got 5 values` the suggested solution does not work anymore in `0.19.12`

Comment: You need to update `date_range` to `date_ranges` now; this commit https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/pull/10005 better distinguished between generating single/multiple date (or datetime) ranges, and it landed in polars `0.18.9`.

Comment: Thanks @alexander-beedie - looks like saturating changed too, will update. As the new function returns a list, would `date_range_list` be a more applicable name I wonder.